# How to get the INPUT element the next keystroke will write to?

Tags: javascript, focus

I have some HTML / JS application I like to test by injecting dummy user input.

I tried to use `document.activeElement` to find the INPUT / TEXTAREA I push the simulated input to, but quite often `activeElement` just points to `document.body`. Entering real keystrokes will let some browser magic happen, that snaps focus to some (the first?) visible INPUT element on the page and put the character just entered there.

Is this magic always the case, and does this happen in a reliable manner? What JS code will resemble this "magic" ?

Comment: Just typing does not automatically focus an element. You'll need to show your HTML for concrete help.